# Integrals and Laplace Operator with a Commutator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, commutator

If I have a Hamiltonian which looks like:

$H=\int_{}^{}  \psi(x)^\dagger \nabla^2_{x} \psi(x)d^3x $

and a total number operator like:

$N=\int_{}^{}  \psi(x)^\dagger  \psi(x)d^3x $

and I want to calculate the commutator. Can I just pull the integral and the Laplace operator out of my commutator?

$[N,H] = [\int_{}^{}  \psi(x)^\dagger  \psi(x)d^3x ,\int_{}^{}  \psi(x')^\dagger \nabla^2_{x} \psi(x')d^3x']= \int_{}^{} \int_{}^{} \nabla^2_{x}[ \psi(x)^\dagger  \psi(x), \psi(x')^\dagger  \psi(x')]d^3xd^3x' $

is this allowed or is there some kind of relation as I could not find anything. Also the $\psi(x)$ should be vectors but im not as experienced with the formatting.

Comment: Integral - yes. Laplace operator - no, because $\nabla_{x'}^2$ (NOT $\nabla_x^2$) acts only on one of the $\psi(x')$, not both of them.

Answer (score 2):

Pulling the integral out should absolutely work, since you introduced different integration variables for both operators. So as far as $x$ is concerned, everything that depends on $x'$ is just a constant that can be pulled in and out of the integral as you want. (Assuming everything is nicely convergent).

With the Laplace operator, you have to be more careful. The way you wrote the last equation, makes it act on both $\psi(x)^\dagger$ and $\psi(x)$. But in your definition of $H$, it only acts on $\psi(x)$ So this cannot be correct. I think the best thing to do would be to write out the expansion of $\psi(x)$ in terms of creation/annihilation operators, then take the derivative and then calculate the commutator $$[\nabla_x^2 \psi(x), \psi(x')].$$
Also note that if you have products of fields inside commutators, you can make use of the relation
$$[ab,c] = a[b,c] + [a,c]b.$$

Comment: How would I go about writing $\psi(x)$ in creation/annihilation operators? I have tried to just solve it with the relation you named but I end up in a dead end.